# Installing multiple Zope versions

Tags: python, zope

I'd like to install multiple Zope 2 versions on one of my servers. I have already done this with versions 2.8, 2.9 and 2.13, so I know that I have to take care of the different python versions.

Now in my case I'd like to set up 2.13.19 and 2.13.21. They can share the same python version with no problem. But it seems that easy_install won't let me install the newer version in addition to the older. Is it because they are so close?

Why would I want this? It's on a production server, I don't want to update the instances already running without testing that everything works fine. But I'd like to create new instances with the newest Zope version.

I didn't install Zope using virtualenv, so maybe that's the way to go? Can I use virtualenv in addition to a standard Python environment? Does it have any performance issues?

Comment: That's what you need to use a virtualenv or buildout for. There are no performance issues with that.

Comment: I tried to install Zope using buildout. Unfortunately the docs both on http://docs.zope.org/zope2/releases/2.13/INSTALL-buildout.html and in the INSTALL-buildout.rst file are wrong: the download path is broken (I found out the right one), and now I don't know how to bootstrap as there is no bootstrap.py nor buildout.cfg in the sources.

Comment: The buildout files are still there in the 2.13.19 release, but already missing in 2.13.20.

Comment: You can copy them safely from an older version.

Comment: I already hat that idea but they rely on sources.cfg and versions.cfg and I suspected there could be some changes from 2.13.19 to 2.13.21. Do you think it's safe to get these files too? Do they only change on major releases?

Comment: Thanks again, Martijn, it did work out :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! The `sources.cfg` you don't really need; it won't change between minor versions. You can always grab missing files from the [`2.13.21` tag](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/tree/2.13.21) on github.

Comment: Thank you again, on github the files are complete. The old versions.cfg obviously had Zope version 2.13.19 ;)

Comment: That does sound like a serious bug, could you report that to the [Zope issue tracker](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/issues)?

Comment: No, no the files from github are ok! I meant the file I had copied before from the old version. D

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using virtualenv, Each Zope-Version residing in its own environment from which I can create the Zope- and ZEO-instances I need.